C++/CLI library for .NET 6 - how to reference .NETCoreApp?
I am trying to port a C++/CLI library .vcxproj project from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6.
The guide at MS says:


Replace <TargetFrameworkVersion> properties with <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>. Be sure to change the tag and value.


Ok, I want to target .NET 6 rather than .NET 8 for now1, but that modification seems trivial. I have tried the following elements in the <PropertyGroup Label="Globals"> section of my .vcxproj file:

<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<TargetFramework>.netcoreapp6.0</TargetFramework> as suggested in another answer

Both of these yield the following compiler error:

Your project does not reference ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0" framework. Add a reference to ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore.

Now, if I do use <TargetFrameworks>.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0</TargetFrameworks> instead of the above <TargetFramework> element, the compiler outputs the following error instead:

NETSDK1013
The TargetFramework value '' was not recognized. It may be misspelled. If not, then the TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or TargetFrameworkVersion properties must be specified explicitly.

From here, I have tried two things:

I have specified the two values as suggested:
<TargetFrameworks>.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFrameworkIdentifier>.NETCoreApp</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>6.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>


I have used both <TargetFramework> and <TargetFrameworks> together:
<TargetFrameworks>.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>


I have used <TargetFramework> and <TargetFrameworkVersion> together:
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v6.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>


I have used <TargetFramework>, <TargetFrameworkVersion>, and <TargetFrameworks> together:
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v6.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
<TargetFrameworks>.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0</TargetFrameworks>



In each case, I get the first error message again.
How can I solve this?

Here is my full .vcxproj files, with some anonymization applied, and minus the various attempts at solving the compiler error as described above:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>[some guid]</ProjectGuid>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Keyword>ManagedCProj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>[namespace]</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    <ProjectName>[project name]</ProjectName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
    <CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
    <CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
    <ReferencePath>$(VC_ReferencesPath_x64);..\Libraries</ReferencePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <LinkIncremental>false</LinkIncremental>
    <ReferencePath>$(VC_ReferencesPath_x64);..\Libraries</ReferencePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>[folder paths]</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <TreatWarningAsError>true</TreatWarningAsError>
      <DisableSpecificWarnings>4691;%(DisableSpecificWarnings)</DisableSpecificWarnings>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>[.lib files]</AdditionalDependencies>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>[folder paths]</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalOptions>/ignore:4099 %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
    </Link>
    <PreBuildEvent>
      <Command>[some PowerShell commands]</Command>
    </PreBuildEvent>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level4</WarningLevel>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>NDEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>[folder paths]</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <Optimization>Disabled</Optimization>
      <TreatWarningAsError>true</TreatWarningAsError>
      <DisableSpecificWarnings>4691;%(DisableSpecificWarnings)</DisableSpecificWarnings>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>[.lib files]</AdditionalDependencies>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>[folder paths]</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
    </Link>
    <PreBuildEvent>
      <Command>[some PowerShell commands]</Command>
    </PreBuildEvent>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Unity">
      <HintPath>..\Libraries\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <HintPath>..\Libraries\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    [some internal .NET assembly references]
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="[.h file]" />
    [more .h file includes]
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="AssemblyInfo.cpp">
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
      <PrecompiledHeader Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
    </ClCompile>
    [more .cpp file compile elements]
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ResourceCompile Include="app.rc" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Image Include="app.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    [a project reference to a C# project in the same solution]
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>


1: I know .NET 6 is approaching the end of its support period. But this is part of a very large project with lots of .NET 6 assemblies and a full migration to .NET 8 is going to happen in the next weeks. Until then, everything should stay on .NET 6.

The error message is misleading, tuned for SDK-style projects.  You can only use TargetFramework and select "net6.0".  We can't see the context of the error message and what might be wrong with the generated project.runtimeconfig.json file.

@HansPassant: I don't have a .runtimeconfig.json file anywhere in that project. Should I? From the information I gather in the migration guide, it sounds like that file only becomes relevant once the application is executed (for otherwise, whether or not a given library I'm compiling will later on be called from a managed entrypoint is typically none of the compiler's business at the time of compilation).

We are now targeting 5.0 but we first migrated to 6.0
What we have in our projects :
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
...
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v6.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
...

and for Debug and Release :
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
...
    <CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport>
...

This had be found in the porting guide
Please be aware of this (mentionned in the porting guide but I didn't put enough attention at first... got some side effects after...). We used this hack to help with that but it adds some ugly code.
The .runtimeconfig.json should be generated for you during compilation. It is mandatory for the first dll loaded. No effects during compilation.
Here is a new vcxproj file which is compiling on my environnment :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>17.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{CB991AA4-C3C7-41A0-90F0-082BE7BAD48D}</ProjectGuid>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Keyword>ManagedCProj</Keyword>
    <RootNamespace>NetCoreCppPOC</RootNamespace>
    <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
    <CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
    <CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
    <CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
    <CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport>
    <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies />
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies />
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies />
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level3</WarningLevel>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>NDEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies />
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
</Project>


Unfortunately, using both <TargetFrameworkVersion> and <TargetFramework> does not change anything for me - compilation is still failing with 'Your project does not reference ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0" framework. Add a reference to ".NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore.'. I had already added the <CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport> elements before.

Could you post the full content of the vcxproj ? I'll see on monday for a working example

I have added an anonymized version of the .vcxproj file to the question. Do you think there is any fundamental difference compared to your project file?

seems good to me, what version of Visual Studio are you using ?

I have added a working example

Thank you - I am investigating what could be the crucial difference between your project file and mine.

Did you try to clean the bin and obj folder ? Maybe some previous compilation left something....

Unfortunately, removing obj and x64 (bin was already not there anymore) doesn't change anything.
